# How to use Spinner to Save selection to shared preference

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner view called `Spinner_Gender`, I made array, array adapter and made `onItemSelectedListener`.  I want to save the selected item position which is integer to shared preference, I tried using a string with Editor and putInt, it saved well.  But when reloading the saved data to the spinner using `.setSelection` it gives an error because it wants an integer not string.  Also while trying Integer in sharedpreference I can't save the selected item position to it because the putInt needs only a string to put int in.

Sorry for long question but I searched a lot and can't find answer.  Two more questions please:
what is the integer name for spinner `selectedItemPosition`? How can I store it to `sharedpreference`?

Code:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_Gender);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, 
                                final int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) 
      { 
          int selectedPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(); 
          Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit(); 
          editor.putInt(myNum,selectedPosition); 
          editor.commit(); 
      }
}
```

Comment: What method you are using to retrieve the int from SharedPrefrence?

Comment: spinner.setSelection(mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_Gender, 0));

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what's your issue with SharedPreferences.
When you want to save the value you do something like this :

```
SharedPreferences test = getSharedPreferences("TEST", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
Editor editTest = test.edit();
editTest.putInt("key", id_from_spinner);
editTest.commit();
```

When you want to get the value you do something like this :

```
SharedPreferences test = getSharedPreferences("TEST", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
int id = test.getInt("key", -1);
if(id != -1) {
    //use it in your spinner
} else {
    //abort because value was not set
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If the response resolves your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an int to a String you can use `Integer.toString(theInteger)` and to convert a String to an int you can use `Integer.parseInt(theString)`.

Comment: Tried converting but no luck it hangs

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
spinner.setSelection(dataAdapter.getPosition(genderstring));
```

### Update :

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_Gender);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 

spinner.setSelection(mGameSettings.getInt("gender", 0));

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() { 
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, 
                                final int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) 
      { 
          Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit(); 
          editor.putInt("gender", selectedItemPosition); 
          editor.commit(); 
      }
}
```

Comment: does not work , what dataAdapter spinner use ArrayAdapter anyway thanks

Comment: final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_Gender);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     
     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
       new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, 
       final int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) {
        int selectedPosition = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();      
           editor.putInt(myNum,selectedPosition);
           editor.commit();
           
       }